# If $|z-i|<1$ what can we deduce about $|z-1|$ and $|z+i|$

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

If $|z-i|<1$ what can we deduce about how large or small $|z-1|$ and $|z+i|$
could be?

I tried drawing a diagram to get a feel but I don't know how to do anything more.

I feel like $ 1< |z+i|<3$ based on diagram but how can I go about the $|z-1|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diagram will certainly help you.

It also helps to think of $|z_1-z_2|$ as being the distance between two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ plotted in the argand diagram.

So you know from $|z-i|<1$ that $z$ lives somewhere 1 unit or less away from the point represented by $i$. That gives you a circle as the locus of points $z$.

$|z-1|$ is the distance from $z$ to the point represented by $1$. What is the closest point on the circle to $1$ and what is the furthest point on the circle from $1$?

[image]

Comment: " What is the closest point on the circle to 1 and what is the furthest point on the circle from 1?" I don't know that is the problem.

Comment: Draw a circle centered at $(0,i)$ with radius $1$. $z$ must lie inside this circle. Then join the point $(0,i)$ to $(1,0)$. Then length of this line is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=\sqrt{2}$. The distance from $(0,i)$ to the edge of the circle is $1$. Therefore the closest point that $z$ comes to the point $(1,0)$ must be $\sqrt{2}-1$. Use similar logic to find the furherest point.

Comment: Okay so is $1<|z+i|<3$ and $\sqrt 2-1<|z-1|<\sqrt 2+1$ correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If $|z-i| < 1$, then, using triangle inequality:

$|z-1| \leq |z-i| + |i - 1| < 1 + \sqrt{2} $.

$|z+i| \leq |z-i| + |i + i| < 1 + \sqrt{2}$.

Which is also observable in a diagram.

Comment: I like that! Could you get the lower bound in a similar way?

Comment: Thinking about this more, how do you know that that is the least upper bound?

Comment: It's in the nature of the triangle inequality. You could take one of the two $z$'s, such that $z,i$ and $1$ are collinear, the one such that $|z-1| = |z-i| + |i-1|$. And the least upper bound there is determined by the least upper bound of $|z-i|$, which is 1. All the other $z$'s are closer to the origin then, because they would make the inequality a strict inequality. So you can't go bigger than that.

Answer (score 1):

First, draw the disk corresponding to the inequality.  Then determine the maximum and minimum distance between a point in that disk and the point $1$ (for $z-1$) or $-i$ (for $z+i$).

Comment: Yes I have done that. It is easy for $|z+i|$ because it is just a straight line but I am stuck on how to do the other.